# C# letters like å not correctly shown in output file

Tags: c#, encoding, streamwriter

I work in C# and this is my code:

```
        Encoding encoding;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        //somePath is string
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(somePath))
        {
            string line;
            encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //make some changes to line
                output.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(someOtherPath, false))//encoding
        {
            writer.Write(output);
        }
```

In the file which is on somePath, I have Norwegian characters like å. But, on the file in someOtherPath I get question marks instead of them.  I think it's an encoding problem, so I tried getting the input file encoding and to grant it to the output file. It had no results. I tried opening the file with Google Chrome and grant it every possible encoding but the letters weren't the same as in the input file.

Comment: @leppie Encoding.Default Gets an encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page. 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx)

Comment: @sailor: Yes, I know that, and why I suggested it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StreamReader` can only make guesses with regards to certain encodings. Ideally, you should find out what the encoding of the file *really* is, then use that to read the file. What created the file, and what allows you to read it correctly? Does the latter program expose which encoding it's using? (For example, it may be using something like Windows-CP1252.)

I would *personally* recommend using UTF-8 as your output encoding if you can, but it depends on whether you're in control over whatever's then reading the output.

EDIT: Okay, now I've seen the file, I can confirm it's *not* UTF-8. The word "direktør" is represented as these bytes:

```
64 69 72 65 6b 74 f8 72
```

So the non-ASCII character is a single byte (F8) which is *not* a valid UTF-8 representation of a character.

It *could* be ISO-Latin-1 - it's not clear (there are multiple encodings which would match). If it is, you can use:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);

using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, encoding))
{
    ...
}
```

(Alternatively, use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) to make life simpler.)

You'll need to separately work out what *output* encoding you want.

EDIT: Here's a short but complete program which I've run against the file you provided, and which has correctly converted the character to UTF-8:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("file.html", encoding))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                output.AppendLine("Read line: " + line);
            }
        }
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("output.html", false))
        {
            writer.Write(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It IS UTF-8. When I open the input file in Chrome with UTF-8 the letters are ok. When I open the output file in Chrome with UTF-8, the letters are bad.

Comment: @Srcee: Given that `StreamReader` defaults to UTF-8, that sounds unlikely to me. Either your changes are messing things up, or Chrome is *actually* accommodating for a different encoding. Can you open the file in a *binary* editor and post the bytes used to make up the Norwegian characters?

Comment: I opened the input file with binary editor and it has correct letters. Here are the bytes:
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'>direktør</p>

Comment: @Srcee: Those aren't bytes, those are characters. I'm talking about the *raw bytes*.

Comment: Ok, for one character the bytes are 11111000.

Comment: @Srcee: That's a single byte, for a non-ASCII character - which immediately means it's *not* UTF-8, *or* there are actually multiple bytes but you've only told me about one of them.

Comment: No, I selected only one letter and then selected the option to see its bites and it gave me that byte. And in my code, when I debug, sr.CurrentEncoding has the value UTF-8.

Comment: @Srcee: Ignore the value of `sr.CurrentEncoding` - it will only detect between UTF-8 and UTF-16 IIRC (when you don't specify an encoding). You need to look carefully in a binary editor to see which bytes (probably plural) are responsible for that character. Or put the file somewhere on the web so that we can look at it ourselves.

Comment: The result is the same. The language is Norwegian. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @Srcee: The language doesn't determine the encoding, but if you specify the coding as `Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)` it *will* read that file appropriately. Are you still saving it with UTF-8? If so, can you provide the output file?

Comment: I'm not, I changed the code as you told me. Here is the output file: http://www.mediafire.com/?0mzpamjetmap1mj

Comment: @Srcee: What output encoding are you using though? I only suggested changing the *input* encoding. Can you edit your post with the code you're now using?

Comment: Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"newOutputPath", false, encoding))
            {
                writer.Write(newOutput);
            }

Comment: @Srcee: See my most recent edit for a short but complete program for you to test.

Comment: @Srcee: Look at the code I posted earlier - it's the encoding for the *reader*, not the *writer*. Your file is not UTF-8, so you need to tell the *reader* what encoding to *read* it with.

Comment: I applyied your code and instead of ø, now it shows ÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â.

Comment: @Srcee: "it" being? What does the binary for the file look like? It's not clear what you're viewing this file in. But my code definitely *does* convert the file you gave from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

Comment: By 'it' I mean the output file. I'm seeing it in Google Chrome. Did you try it on the file I gave you?

Comment: @Srcee: There's nothing in the HTML to specify which encoding it's using, so Chrome is guessing - incorrectly in this case. Ideally, your HTML should specify which encoding it's using.

Comment: I used your code but with one change and it worked!
the change was: I specified the encoding in the streamwriter too. Thank you very very much, you really helped.

Comment: @Srcee: I did explicitly say: "You'll need to separately work out what output encoding you want." :) Anyway, I'm glad it works for you now...

Answer (score 1):

Try this case to save your text:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(someOtherPath, Encoding.UTF8)) { ... }
```